# TaskWarrior automatically modify UDA

Tags: taskwarrior

I have a question. Let's say that I have created User Defined Attribute `attr` with values `A,B,C`.
How to configure taskwarrior to automatically change the `attr` value from `A` to `B` when I enter

> task x start

and change `attr` from `B` to `C` when

> task x done

Answer (score 0):

**Disadvantage of suggested solution:**

1. You continuously need to have a script running in the background.
2. There can occur a small delay between your `task x start` command, and the change of UDA `attr`
3. It is a bit of a tedious method, perhaps you can also accomplish your goal using solely taskwarrior commands/settings.
4. It is made for fun and I can currently not offer any security or proper functioning guarantees. I tested and use it on `WSL Ubuntu 16.04`.

**Assumptions:**

If you enter `task x start` the attribute `Start` is set to a valid date.

**Solution:**

You can have a script running in the background that reads the properties of all tasks, and as soon as it detects a valid date in the `Start` attribute of a tasks, and a value of `B` in the UDA `attr` then it sets the UDA `attr` to `C` by executing the command `task x modify attr:C` command.

[I made a script/small project that sorts on a custom setting of project and urgency](https://github.com/a-t-0/PublicCodeLibrary/tree/master/AutomationAndSystems/Taskwarrior), and it contains the functionalities of:

- Running in the background from startup automatically,
- Scanning the taskproperties and automatically applying the changes that are programmed in the script.

So in effect,

1. You should modify/add the UDA `attr` [here](https://github.com/a-t-0/PublicCodeLibrary/blob/34a3d9d414d86b224189c3ee74a38308ae510820/AutomationAndSystems/Taskwarrior/customSortServerV4/src/customSortServerV4/Task.java):
2. And duplicate and change for example method `private static void setCustomSort(ArrayList<Task> taskList) {`1 on line 88 of the [main](https://github.com/a-t-0/PublicCodeLibrary/blob/92f5fe8d3f1bff83b9fdb16c2e8bf50b105b308b/AutomationAndSystems/Taskwarrior/customSortServerV4/src/customSortServerV4/Main.java)

(For the 2nd step, between `//get uuid` and `//create command` you should add the condition that checks the task for a valid id. Then if it has, change the command that is generated to `task modify attr:C`)

The instructions to compile the java code and set up automation are listed [here](https://github.com/a-t-0/PublicCodeLibrary/tree/master/AutomationAndSystems/Taskwarrior/customSortServerV4).

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It seems like big workaround, but at least we have something ;) Thank you.